# ActionPickerView get result

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have a pickerView linked with a button 
when you click to the Button it will appears ..

my problem is : 
I don't know how to get the result and print it to the textFiled I created..

if I can make the result in the button name without needed to the text filed will be great !!

thats what I did so far :

```
import UIKit
import ActionSheetPicker_3_0


class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
@IBAction func ssss(_ sender: Any) {


    ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.show(withTitle: "Multiple String Picker", rows: [
        ["One", "Two", "A lot"],
        ], initialSelection: [1],

           doneBlock: {


            picker, indexes, values in


            self.text1.text = ("\(values)")

            /**
            print("values = \(values)")
            print("indexes = \(indexes)")
            print("picker = \(picker)")
            return
**/

    },


           cancel: { ActionMultipleStringCancelBlock in return }, origin: sender)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a mistake with the variable name in the `doneBlock` while you are assigning the value to the text field. Also, check out the `initialSelection` parameter. You have provided `[1]` which will select the whole Array.

```
 ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.show(
      withTitle: "Multiple String Picker", 
      rows: [["One", "Two", "A lot"]], 
      initialSelection: [1, 1],
      doneBlock: { picker, indexes, values in
        // self.text1.text = ("\(vslues)")
        // should be
        self.text1.text = ("\(values)")
      },
      cancel: { ActionMultipleStringCancelBlock in return }, 
      origin: sender)
```

Comment: thats right I made a mistake .. all thing now is ok But the result I Gut is : optinal!(<_NSSingleObjectarray 0x618000013ce0>( Two) )

Comment: why its not just ( Two ) ??

Comment: Because `values` is optional. You can force unwrap it using `!`. `self.text1.text = ("\(values!)")`. I would not recommend this way, use optional binding for it i.e. `if let v = values { self.text1.text = "\(v)" }`

Comment: hmm , the result now is : (  Two )  with brackets ! I just want the result be Two . Thank You for the help